# Can a docker build use the url of a git branch?

Tags: docker

According to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#build), a git url can be passed to a build command:
[image]

But what happens if the git url needs to be a branch name? In other words, how do I do the equivalent of this:

> git clone -b my-firefox-branch
>   git@github.com:creack/docker-firefox.git

Comment: I think you have to do in a two step process. First clone the repo, then checkout the branch and then build the image from the Dockerfile

Comment: You could try specifying the branch using # e.g. `git@github.com:creack/docker-firefox.git#development`. Not near a computer though so can't try

Answer (score 7):

Start your URL with `git://` (or `https://`) and simply append the branch name after `#`.

I just forked the OP's repo and created a branch to confirm it works (docker version 1.11.1):

```
root@box:~# docker build git://github.com/michielbdejong/docker-firefox#michielbdejong-patch-1
Sending build context to Docker daemon 52.22 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:12.04
12.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
4edf76921243: Downloading
[==========>                                        ] 9.633 MB/44.3 MB
^Croot@box:~#
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/ for full docs.

Answer (score 2):

So far, No. it can't.

Here's what I got:

```
$ docker build git@github.com:shawnzhu/docker-ruby.git#branch1
2014/12/04 08:19:04 Error trying to use git: exit status 128 (Cloning into '/var/folders/9q/bthxttfj2lq7jtz0b_f938gr0000gn/T/docker-build-git859493111'...
fatal: remote error: 
   is not a valid repository name
  Email support@github.com for help
)
```

If you take a look at [this line](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/client/commands.go#L135) of docker CLI code, it only do recursive git clone against given URL of a git repo (even no `--depth=1`) when using `docker build <git-repo-url>`.

However, it could be an interesting improvement to docker (if people want it) since `#<branch-name>` and `#<commit>` are popular syntax to github URL adopted by lots of tools like [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#git-urls-as-dependencies) and bower.

Comment: You need to use `git://` instead of `git@` at the start of the URL (see my answer below).

Comment: shawmzhu it is indeed possible to pass a branch in the git URL, please check documentation here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/ : "run this command to use a directory called docker in the branch container:

$ docker build https://github.com/docker/rootfs.git#container:docker
"

Comment: This is incorrect, it is possible to do this (see michielbdejong answer)

Answer (score 1):

Well it works more or less depending on versions

For recent versions : (docker-engine 1.5.0-0~trusty and+)

```
docker build https://github.com/rzr/iotjs.git#master
docker build https://github.com/rzr/iotjs.git
docker build github.com/rzr/iotjs.git
```

For older ones: (docker.io 1.4-5ubuntu1 and -)

```
docker build https://github.com/rzr/iotjs.git
docker build git://github.com/rzr/iotjs.git
docker build github.com/rzr/iotjs.git
```

Maybe this can be handled in helper script like:

```
curl -sL https://rawgit.com/rzr/iotjs/master/run.sh | bash -x -
```

Comment: And `docker build github.com/rzr/iotjs#branch` should be working, to address initial poster's question